# Vue seems to "forget" Vuex States

Tags: vuejs3, state, vuex, vue-cli

I am working on an application with a login area.
There are three routes at the moment:

```
"/"
```

Landing page, accessible for every not-logged user
Component set in vue-router: TheIndex.vue

```
"/dashboard"
```

First thing you see after you logged in
Component set in vue-router: TheDashboard.vue

```
"/dashboard/editsets"
```

Where you land after clicking on a button in /dashboard.
Component set in vue-router: TheEditsets.vue

My application fetches potential existent topics from a Database.

everything but "/" - Route should only be accessible if you are logged in.
**Edit:** and that part works. If i change the urls manually in the browser bar, it redirects me exactly where it should be. My problem is that i need the statistics that are meant to be stored in $store for every other interaction of this application, but it doesnt work because sometimes the state is empty.

To keep an eye on that state i log the complete state in the console within the related components with the beforeMount() Method:

**TheDashboard.vue/script/beforeMount():**

```
async beforeMount() {
        console.log(this.$store.state);
        let initial_logincheck = await this.$store.dispatch("checkUserLogged");
        if(initial_logincheck.success) {
            this.$store.commit("login", initial_logincheck.logged_user);
            this.loggedUserName = initial_logincheck.logged_user;
        }
        else {
            console.error("USER NICHT EINGELOGGT!");
        }
        if(this.$store.getters.getLoggedState)
        {
            await this.getTotals();
        }
        else {
            this.$router.push("/");
        }
        console.log(this.$store.state);
    },
```

As you can see, i log this.$store.state two times. First time before the totals are actually set withing the store (that happens in await this.getTotals()) and a second time AFTER they should be set. After i login, there is a first weird behaviour as you can see on those logs:
[both_entries_true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDG5M.png)

I expected the first LOG_INFO_islogged to be false, but it is true but then on the other attributes there are only empty or null-values. Weird but okay, i didnt care bc the second log was as i expected it to be. LOG_INFO_islogged is true and filled with the user data.

But when i refresh the page (with CTRL+F5 but also only with F5) the first entry is false and without any values:
[first_entryy_false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se1mo.png)

That first entry should at this moment also be true and with values because i got them set right before the second console.log when the component was first mounted.

I have no idea why that behaviour is. Especially when i want to use those values for further child components, that retrieve the user data, but i cant because Vue thinks its null or empty.

Why does the store seems to "forget" the values i gave it?

**main.js/store:**

```
//VUE-X
import {createStore} from "vuex";
const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            API                     : "http://localhost/vue_projects/vocabtrainer/backend/main.php",
            LOG_INFO_islogged       : false,
            LOG_INFO_name           : null,
            USER_INFO_totaltopics   : null,
            USER_INFO_totalvocabs   : null,
            USER_topicArray         : [],
            USER_tIdx               : 0,
            USER_vIdx               : 0,
            USER_vocabArray         : [],
        };
    },
    mutations: {
        logout(state) {
            state.LOG_INFO_islogged     = false;
            state.LOG_INFO_name         = null;
            state.USER_INFO_totaltopics = null;
            state.USER_INFO_totalvocabs = null;
            router.push("/");
        },
        login(state, username) {
            state.LOG_INFO_islogged = true;
            state.LOG_INFO_name = username;
            router.push("/dashboard");
        },
        setTotals(state, result) {
            state.USER_INFO_totaltopics = result.totalTopics;
            state.USER_INFO_totalvocabs = result.totalVocabs;
        },
        setTopicStats(state, fetchedTopics) {
            state.USER_topicArray = [...fetchedTopics.topics];
        },
        clearTopicStats(state) {
            state.USER_topicArray.length = 0;
            state.USER_vocabArray.length = 0;
            state.USER_tIdx = 0;
            state.USER_vIdx = 0;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        async post(context, dataobject) {
          [...]
        },
        async checkUserLogged() {
            let checkloggedobject = {task: "is_a_user_logged"};
            let checkloggedresult = await this.dispatch("post", checkloggedobject);
            return checkloggedresult;
        },
    },
    getters: {
        tIndex(state) {
            return state.USER_tIdx;
        },
        getTopicArray(state) {
            return state.USER_topicArray;
        },
        getLoggedState(state) {
            return state.LOG_INFO_islogged;
        },
        getLoggedUsernameState(state) {
            return state.LOG_INFO_name;
        },
        getTopicsCountState(state) {
            return state.USER_INFO_totaltopics;
        },
        getVocabsCountState(state) {
            return state.USER_INFO_totalvocabs;
        },
    },
});
```

**TheDashboard.vue/script:**

```
    data() {
        return {
            loggedUserName  : "",
            totalTopics     : null,
            totalVocabs     : null,
        };
    },
    async beforeMount() {
        console.log(this.$store.state);
        let initial_logincheck = await this.$store.dispatch("checkUserLogged");
        if(initial_logincheck.success) {
            this.$store.commit("login", initial_logincheck.logged_user);
            this.loggedUserName = initial_logincheck.logged_user;
        }
        else {
            console.error("USER NICHT EINGELOGGT!");
        }
        if(this.$store.getters.getLoggedState)
        {
            await this.getTotals();
        }
        else {
            this.$router.push("/");
        }
        console.log(this.$store.state);
    },
    methods: {
        async getTotals() {
            let totalsrequest = {task: "get_totals"};
            let totalresult = await this.$store.dispatch("post", totalsrequest);
            if(totalresult.success) {
                this.$store.commit("setTotals", totalresult);
                this.totalTopics = totalresult.totalTopics;
                this.totalVocabs = totalresult.totalVocabs;
            }
            else {
                console.error("TOTALS NICHT GEHOLT!");
            }
        },
        async logout() {
                [...]
        },

    },
};
```

And here is
**TheEditsets.vue/script:**

```
    data() {
        return {
            // .name, .totalVocabs, .level
            topicArray  : [],
            tIdx        : 0,
            vocabArray  : [],
        };
    },
    computed: {
        getTotalTopics() {
            return this.$store.state.USER_INFO_totaltopics;
        }
    },
    async beforeMount() {
        console.clear();
        console.log(this.$store.state);
        let initial_logincheck = await this.$store.dispatch("checkUserLogged");
        if(!initial_logincheck.success) {
            this.$router.push("/");
            return;
        }
        let allStats = await this.$store.dispatch("post", {task: "fetch_all_topic_stats"});
        this.$store.commit("setTopicStats", allStats);
        console.log(this.$store.state);
    }
};
```

Comment: App instance is destroyed when you reload a page, causing loss of all store data.  Data would need to be saved to browser storage before reload and loaded from storage after.  You can do so manually or Vuex persist plugin can help https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#vuex-persist

Comment: Thnak you very much for that comment. Where does vuex makes sense if it gets destroyed after every reload of the page then? i could make a validation for the login and then instantly save all relevant data into localstorage, or am i missing sth here?

Comment: SPAs don't normally **require** users reload pages for normal use, so plugins like Vuex shouldn't need to persist data within browser storage by default. Any site that persists data across reloads is using something like in-browser storage or cookies. It's fine to use localstorage for your case.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Yes, indeed, SPAs should not be refreshed, i totally agree. But for an application to run smoothly there must be a solution to the case that a user actually refreshes(accidently or for some other reason). What is the best practise here to handle this case?

Comment: The answer is usually either localStorage or cookies.  Storing sensitive information client side is a big topic I'd recommend researching as the best practice for _your_ site will depend.